# How can I select a syntax highlighting at the (shell-) command line?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, invocation

Usually, vim will get the highlighting right from the file extension, but this obviously doesn't work when I'm displaying content read from standard input.

```
cat File.hs | some | processing | pipeline | view -
```

I can obtain the proper highlighting with

```
:set syntax=haskell
```

but that's awkward to do multiple times. How do I select the highlighting right at command-line invocation?

```
cat File.hs | vim -R {???syntax=haskell} -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `+command` to execute `command` after the "file" is loaded:

```
cat File.hs | some | processing | pipeline | vim -R +'setf haskell' -
```

Comment: Great, works. What exactly is `setf`?

Comment: See `:help :setf`.